# MPI, NFS File Writing

Tags: mpi, file-permissions, nfs

I'm having an issue with a MPI program running across a group of Linux nodes. The group is currently set up with NFS, with /home/mpi mounted across all nodes. The problem is that the program requires all of the nodes to open a file in the file system in write mode (use fopen on /home/mpi/file), and write to while it does calculations. One node will be able to open it, and the others won't and will throw an error. Instead I want each node to have its own file to write to.

I was wondering if there was a way to get around this. I was thinking about making a separate file for each node, with the nodes rank appended to the filename, but was wondering if there were simpler ways to get around this issue. Is there a way to set up the group so that all the worker nodes have their own copy of the /home/mpi directory that is auto-updated with any changes that the master node does to its copy?

Thanks.

Comment: In the first paragraph you say that each process opens the file in write mode. In the second it is the master that changes the files and the other ranks consume the updates. This looks different from the former. Could you please elaborate on the I/O pattern of the program.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the standard way of doing things is to open one file per node, indexed by rank as you described. Depending on what these files are used for (e.g. logging), you then have to write a script to re-combine them at the end of the computation.

If you really need all processes to write to the same file on the filesystem, you'll have to somehow coordinate concurrent outputs from all processes wanting to write to the file.

There is no way to do this at the filesystem level as far as I know, but you can do this within you MPI code. The standard, historical implementation of this is to have all MPI processes send messages to rank 0, which is in charge of effectively writing them to the filesystem.

Another option would be to look at the IO features introduced in MPI2, which allow all processes to work on different parts of the same file.

Comment: In my experience, MPI I/O has a steep learning curve -- i.e. you have to learn alot before you can actually do anything -- but is well worth the effort in the long run.